# Li-ion BMS cuts voltage for no obvious reason

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, bms

I recently built my first Li-ion battery pack; it´s just a small one with 4 cells in series.

For pack protection I´m using a 4S BMS I had laying around, it's a balanced version of the kind you can buy for cheap on AliExpress.

[image]

The problem is that the BMS will not give me any output. When measuring voltage at the output, it's 4 times the cell voltage as it is supposed to be.

However, when I add a load of any kind to the output, it will not allow current to flow and voltage drops to around 1 V, sometimes hovering to 2 or 3 V. When I remove the load, the output voltage goes back to 4 times the cell voltage.

I already followed the instructions of the dealer to "activate" the BMS and fully charged the battery with an 18 V voltage source. Charging was cut at a cell voltage of 4.26 V, cells were then balanced down to 4.2 V (resistors were warm).

Still the BMS will cut the voltage whenever a load is added. Then I discharged the pack to 16 V by attaching the load directly to the battery and skipping the BMS, but the problem stays.

The BMS shows the same behaviour when shorting the + and - of the output like it should as Short Circuit Protection. I can't imagine that the short circuit protection always triggers when adding a load - the loads were very light (small buck converters with a microcontroller attached, small LEDs, phone charging PCBs) and inrush current shouldn´t trigger the 40 A limit.

Some additional details:

- Cells are brand new LG M50LT with the same voltage
- The wiring to the BMS is correct. I measured the pads several times and the battery is attached correctly.
- The battery itself works fine, like mentioned before  I could easily use it when skipping the BMS.
- I already tried shorting the B- and Output- to reset the BMS, a hack I found on another forum. Didn´t help.

Does anybody have an idea why I cannot convince the BMS to output?

Comment: Consider that it might be a faulty BMS, either as supplied, or as a result of earlier accidents. One way to kill them instantly is to swap 2 of the intermediate cell connections.

Comment: "fully charged the battery with a 18V voltage source" - not a proper Li-ion charger?

Comment: @user_1818839 that could be, another BMS is already on the way. I might try it tomorrow.

Comment: @Finbarr indeed I used just a voltage source. But how would that influence the BMS?

Comment: The BMS expects a proper charger to supply a constant and regulated current. You may have supplied too much and damaged it. A BMS does not control charging.

Comment: Generally I would agree, but no Charger would allow me to go to the limit where overcurrent protection would start. In the description of the BMS it is even advised to use a 18V source. There is a good chance this BMS is damaged but I think its highly unlikely it was damaged by testing its protection features.

Comment: Which 18V voltage source you used? How many amps it is rated? Still, it makes no sense to connect a voltage source, without a charging circuit, directly to a BMS. For many reasons. If the voltage source can't handle it, it may hiccup and fail to output, or get damaged. If it does manage to charge the battery, 18V is too much for 4 cells and there is nothing to stop charging, except for the BMS overvoltage protection. If it works to cut off the cells from voltage supply.

Comment: I used a boost converter to achieve a current flow of around 200mA into the battery, I monitored cell voltage and adjusted input voltage at the same time to keep that flow constant. I agree that using a charger is the way to go but this is not the point of my question. The overvoltage problem you describe is exactly what I wanted to trigger to try to get the BMS working.

Comment: Today I got another BMS which I attached to my battery. Turns out it works flawlessly. My BMS was just broken then.

Comment: @baschtlwaschtl Not the first time I've seen that response to this exact question.